# fault in sync roaming profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, roaming-profile

I am system admin of a business network.
I am on a Windows XP client. When a user logs off, naturally, it tries to sync changes with server. I noticed that the directory is wrong. It tries to sync with `\\older-server-name\Home Directories`. I checked the static IP, DNS IP, domain to which the PC belongs, and all are okay. Any ideas? 
I have two DNS servers, both running Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually defined in the user properties panel in Active Directory. Check there and change if necessary.

Comment: if it's not defined in the user properties check for a gpo that defines the server share for the roaming profile.